# How to turn Symfony form validators into JavaScript ones?

Tags: javascript, symfony1, validation

I want to turn Symfony form validators into JavaScript validators. I have seen a number of plugins capable of that, but the question is simple: which one do you guys use (and why)?

These are the ones I have seen:

http://blog.adryjanek.eu/2009/01/15/symfony-12-using-sfform-with-jquery-validate-plugin/

http://shout.setfive.com/2009/01/23/client-side-validation-for-the-new-symfony-forms-with-jquery/

Comment: Please don't forget that client-side validation can *never* replace server-side validation, it can merely improve the user experience of the website visitor.

Comment: Nice reminder, but im not looking for a replace, what i want is the same validation in js and in the server

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that does the trick, I've used it, it helps a lot but it isn't perfect. But the idea is here, take a look at the code.

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfJqueryFormValidationPlugin

Comment: Huuum, i have been trying to use that plugin for a while, followed instructions and added a "$("#edit_form").validate();});" in the template but it doest work. Can you please tell me the steps you followed to make the plugin work?

Comment: @Alberto The first thing I noticed was the filter: it's supposed to add a JS file inclusion, but I couldn't make it work. So you have to manually include this JS file in your template, this way: <?php use_dynamic_javascript(url_for('sfJqueryFormVal/' . get_class($form))); ?>